# how can i add version info to the build .exe file using spld SICStus

Tags: cmd, compilation, linker, sicstus-prolog

I have the following batch program that is used to build my Prolog program.

```
set /p VERSION="Enter Version:"
call "c:\Program Files (x86)\SICStus Prolog VC12 4.3.2\bin\sicstus.exe" -l build_program.pl -a %VERSION%

call "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\bin\vcvars32.bat"  
call "C:\Program Files (x86)\SICStus Prolog VC12 4.3.2\bin\spld.exe" --output="fox_optimizer.exe" --static "fox_optimizer.sav"



output="my_program.exe" --static "my_program.sav" --resources=VERSIONINFO.rc
```

the VERSION variable is read from the user and sent as a flag to the build_program.pl that does this:

```
:- 
    nl,nl,nl,
    prolog_flag(argv, Arguments),
    Arguments = [VersionNumber|_],
    atom_concat('fox_optimizer_',VersionNumber,FinalFileToCompile),
    nl,
    write('Trying to complile: '),
    write(FinalFileToCompile),
    nl,nl,nl,
    compile(FinalFileToCompile),
    save_program('my_program.sav'),
    halt.
```

besically it builds the .sav file that is then used by spld to build into .exe file.

I want to add meta-data to the build .exe and i know that wjen using c++ you have to add a resource file so i tried this ..

```
output="my_program.exe" --static "my_program.sav" --resources=VERSIONINFO.rc
```

where VERSIONINFO.rc is:

```
VS_VERSION_INFO VERSIONINFO
 FILEVERSION 1,0,0,1
 PRODUCTVERSION 1,0,0,1
 FILEFLAGSMASK 0x3fL
#ifdef _DEBUG
 FILEFLAGS 0x1L
#else
 FILEFLAGS 0x0L
#endif
 FILEOS 0x40004L
 FILETYPE 0x2L
 FILESUBTYPE 0x0L
BEGIN
    BLOCK "StringFileInfo"
    BEGIN
        BLOCK "000904b0"
        BEGIN
            VALUE "CompanyName", "Britannica Knowledge Systems"
            VALUE "FileDescription", "Fox Optimizer"
            VALUE "FileVersion", "1.0.0.1"
            VALUE "InternalName", "fox_optimizer.exe"
            VALUE "LegalCopyright", "Copyright (C) 2016"
            VALUE "OriginalFilename", "fox_optimizer.exe"
            VALUE "ProductName", "Fox Optimizer"
            VALUE "ProductVersion", "1.0.0.1"
        END
    END
    BLOCK "VarFileInfo"
    BEGIN
        VALUE "Translation", 0x9, 1200
    END
END
```

but when running spld i get the following error

> cl : Command line warning D9024 : unrecognized source file type
>   'VERSIONINFO.rc', object file assumed VERSIONINFO.rc : fatal error
>   LNK1136: invalid or corrupt file

Answer (score 1):

The `spld` option `--resources` has nothing to do with Windows resources. What you want is to compile the `.rc` file to a `.res` file (using the `rc` tool) and pass that `.res` file to the C compiler (via `spld`) together with the other object files. Something like the following:

```
call "rc VERSIONINFO.rc"

call "C:\Program Files (x86)\SICStus Prolog VC12 4.3.1\bin\spld.exe" -v --output="my_program.exe" --static "my_program.sav" VERSIONINFO.res
```

This will embed the Windows resource file in the executable created by `spld`.

I added the `-v` flag to turn on some verbose debug information from `spld`. This is useful when troubleshooting.